# Get Autocomplete form data from Angular Form

Tags: angular

Using `Angular 8` and `material`. Using `reactive` form. I am able to get all other fields using `formControl` except the autocomplete one.

```
  <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text"
      formControlName="analysisDescription" 
      placeholder="Analysis Description"
      matInput [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**.Ts**

```
export class PreTflFormComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  public ADNames: any;
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  form: FormGroup;
  public meetingId: number;


  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PreTflFormComponent>,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private genericService: GenericService,
    private srapiService: SrapiService
  ) {

    this.form = fb.group({
      analysisDescription: [null],
      emails: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.genericService.getADNames().subscribe(data => {
      this.ADNames = data;

      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );

    });

  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {

    if (value.length > 1) { 
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
      return this.ADNames.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    }
  }

}
```

The `analysisDescription` property is always null. I even tried putting `formControlName="analysisDescription"` on `mat-autocomplete` div rather than `<input>` one, I get null only in `form.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are associating two form controls with your input by using `formControlName="analysisDescription"` and `[formControl]="myControl"` at the same time. and obviously `[formControl]="myControl"` is taking precedence. you should remove `[formControl]="myControl"` and use alredy existing control defined 
 in form builder as `this.form.controls.analysisDescription.valueChanges` for auto complete as well.

Comment: but I need `[formControl]="myControl"` for autocomletion suggestions.

Comment: can't I use same `"myControl"` to get the value also? I for most of the part copied it from `material` documentation.

Comment: you don’t need `this.myControl` for autocomplete suggestions. you already have a formControl on your input which is `this.fb.get(“analysisDescription”)` use that control for auto complete as well.

Comment: I think you meant `this.form.get` instead of `this.fb.get` because `formbuilder` don't have get property. But using `this.form.get('analysisDescription').valuechanges.pipe(.....` throws error `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null`

Comment: `this.form.controls.analysisDescription.valueChanges` works